# Pygame Random keystrokes

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a game where keys are randomly selected and appear on the screen, and the player has to click on them. How to implement a check for pressing the desired key ?

```py
unic1=random.randint(0,9)
unic2=random.randint(0,9)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == "pygame.K_"+ str(unic1):
            x2+=10
            unic1=random.randint(0,9)
        elif event.key != "pygame.K_" + str(unic1):
            x2-=10
            unic1=random.randint(0,9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpad has the ley cods from `pygame.K_KP0` to `pygame.K_KP9`.

Create a list of the keys:

```py
key_list = [pygame.K_KP0, pygame.K_KP1, pygame.K_KP2, pygame.K_KP3, pygame.K_KP4
            pygame.K_KP5, pygame.K_KP6, pygame.K_KP7, pygame.K_KP8, pygame.K_KP9]
```

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to choose a random key:

```py
random_key = random.choice(key_list)
```

The keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) create a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object with additional attributes. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute (e.g. `K_RETURN` , `K_a`) and the `mod` attribute contains a bitset with additional modifiers (e.g. `KMOD_LSHIFT`). The `unicode` attribute provides the Unicode representation of the keyboard input.

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == random_key:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))  
            # [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.key.name(event.key)
```

will return the key name (a, b, c, 1, 2, 3) etc.  You can use this to test for the correct key being pressed:

```
if pygame.key.name(event.key) == str(unic1):
  # the key was pressed
```

Comment: Do you know how to use it with numpad?

Comment: just try and print out what it returns. Then you'll know what to use.